# How to retrieve active CustomTextEditor in VSCode

Tags: visual-studio-code

I implemented and registered a CustomTextEditorProvider as shown in the [Custom Text Editor example](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-extension-samples/tree/master/custom-editor-sample)

```
export class MyCustomEditorProvider implements vscode.CustomTextEditorProvider{
 public static register(context: vscode.ExtensionContext): vscode.Disposable {
    const provider = new MyCustomEditorProvider(context);
    const providerRegistration = vscode.window.registerCustomEditorProvider(MyCustomEditorProvider.viewType, provider);
    return providerRegistration;
  }
}
```

now I'd like to perform an action when a command is called and a Custom Editor is active (focused).

The problem is that the api vscode.window.activeTextEditor returns undefined if my Editor is focused. Is this the intended behaviour of the api?
I couldn't find any other api for retrieving the active non-text Editor, is there one?

any help is appreciated

Answer (score 2):

Yes `vscode.window.activeTextEditor` is expected to be undefined when the user focused on a custom editor because a custom editor is not a `TextEditor`.

Custom editors are private to an extension (other extension should not able to interact with them) so you need to track the active editor inside your extension. You can do this using the `onDidChangeViewState` event on the custom editor's webview. It will fire when a custom editor is focused and unfocused